# Error: failed to get accounts owned by program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, spl-associated-token-account

I am trying to find all the token accounts that belong to a specific wallet address however i keep getting this error:
Error: failed to get accounts owned by program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key

my code:

```
const filters:solanaWeb3.GetProgramAccountsFilter[] = [
                    {
                        dataSize:156
                    },
                    {
                        memcmp:{
                            offset:32,
                            bytes:newPub.toString()
                        }
                    }
                ]
                const tA = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,{filters})
```

Answer (score 1):

Token program has one of the largest sets of accounts on Solana and is usually excluded by many RPC nodes for performance reasons. If you are using any publicly available (and free to use) RPC nodes, the chances are that it's excluded.

You can use quicknode or other hosted/paid RPC nodes - it should work.